# MS SQL Server 2014 management studio: No way to edit data in result grid of a view with joined tables

Tags: sql-server

The title says it all. Maybe it is possible in other versions of MS SQL Server management studio but not in the 2014 version ... the grid data remain ineditable.
Can anybody tell me if there is a way in the 2014 version?

Comment: Does the view have an Instead of Update trigger on it?

Comment: A view is basically the results of some predefined SELECT statement.  You can affect the way that it generates, but no permanent changes are going to be written to the tables that generated the view.  Am I understanding your question correctly?  If you want to edit a table, use an UPDATE command.  I'm kind of confused about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can't edit views that join multiple tables. Regardless of version. Unless there is an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on the view to handle the mechanics of the update.

Comment: Are you using the "select all rows" from the view's context menu? It won't work if you're using a query window with a `SELECT` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - if the view is considered "updatable". Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view which discusses "how" and links to "create view" where the restrictions are discussed.